# How to generate Basic authentication code with NSwagStudio?

Tags: swagger-2.0, nswag, nswagstudio

I am using NSwagStudio to generate the client classes/code from an Swagger 2.0 JSON file.

Previously, it used to generate the following authentication code:

```csharp
//Authentication
var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("username:password");
string encodedAuth = System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
request_.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", encodedAuth);
```

Now it's not generating the above-mentioned `Authorization` header. What changes should I make in the JSON file to ensure that the generated code has the authentication code as above?

Comment: Swagger UI is a documentation renderer, it does not generate client classes/code. Do you mean [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen)? If so, which versions of Codegen did you use before and now, and how do you run the Codegen? Also, does your Swagger JSON file include the `securityDefinitions` and `security` sections that [define Basic auth](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/basic-authentication/)?

Comment: I am using NSwagStudio (apologies for saying Swagger UI). The swagger json file has `securityDefinitions` (but no `security`)

(I am new developer trying to add new features., so I am not sure which versions of Codegen was used before)

Comment: Nswag does not generate auth code - you need to add it to the partial class or with one of the availbale extension points

Answer (score 1):

To define authentication, OpenAPI 2.0 Specification uses two keywords:

- `securityDefinitions`
- `security`

`securityDefinitions` describes the security type (e.g. Basic, API key and so on), and `security` applies it to all or specific operations. Without `security`, `securityDefinitions` does not have any effect.

If all operations use Basic authentication, apply `security` at the root level:

```json
{
  "swagger": "2.0",

  "securityDefinitions": {
    "basicAuth": {
      "type": "basic"
    }
  },
  "security": [
    {
      "basicAuth": []
    }
  ],
  ...
}
```

If a specific operation uses Basic auth, apply `security` to that specific operation:

```json
{
  "swagger": "2.0",

  "securityDefinitions": {
    "basicAuth": {
      "type": "basic"
    }
  },
  "paths": {
    "/foo": {
      "get": {
        "security": [
          {
            "basicAuth": []
          }
        ],
        ...
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

More information: [Basic Authentication (OpenAPI 2.0)](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/basic-authentication/)

Comment: thank you for this.. but where do I specify the username and password? lets imaging the username is "abc", and password is "def".. thank you..